# Is it possible to execute Firebase asynchronous callbacks in a background thread?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, firebase

Firebase's asynchronous callback functions are executed in the main/UI thread (see answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178165/firebase-asynchronous-function-whats-in-the-background-queue-and-whats-not)). Is it possible to make Firebase execute them in an alternative thread?

Comment: Sure - write code in your Firebase listener that schedules work you want to perform on another thread.  You can do this for both Android and iOS.

Comment: @doug how do you do this for iOS?